# How to customize the result in "Create HTML Table" in Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-table-storage

I am querying the Azure Table Storage and try to formatting the results. But it is not coming as expected.

I have two string columns and one datetime column. The result coming with "odata.etag". And When I try to show the datetime column (called "EndDate"), additionally it shows one more column as "EndDate@odata.type" with value as "Edm.DateTime"

[image]

Below are my questions.

1. How to achieve it using "Custom" (as in above picture)
2. And Header, not allowing space. (for example: First Name). Is there any way to achive it?

Or any other way to get a customized HTML format of Get Entities result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1.** Please refer to my logic app to solve your question:

[image]

[image]

You can use `Parse Json` to parse the json result from "Get entities" action first.

You can click "Use sample payload to generate schema" button and input the json result into the box to generate the schema automatically.

Then you can use [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#select-action) action to select the data you want.

Finally, you convert the json from `select` to html, and select `Automatic` in `Columns`.

**2.** If you want to customize Html, you can write `First Name` in `Notepad++` or other text editor first, then copy and paste it into `azure logic app`.

If you use `select` action, you don't need to customize the data, you can define the header in `select` action, you can refer to my logic app for details.

The result is like this:

[image]

========================update========================

**1.** Alphabetical order

Based on JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) standards, these action definitions appear in [alphabetical order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-data-operations-code-samples). So the problem you encounter is an expected problem.

[image]

After my test, you can solve the sorting problem in `Create HTML table` action, you need to customize fields:

[image]

The expression of your field value:

```
item()?['<json-array-property-name>']
```

**2.** border

You can directly use tags to add styles：

[image]

HTML:

```
<style>
#testID table, table th, table td {border: 1px solid #F00}
</style>
<div id="testID">
<body of 'Create_HTML_table'>
</div>
```

Because Microsoft removed the `Is HTML` argument, you must write the HTML in the variable first, or you'll send plain text, you can refer to this [blog](https://blog.sandro-pereira.com/2020/01/26/logic-apps-how-to-send-a-well-formatted-html-email-notification-with-office-365-outlook-connector/).

I did a test:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is working for me. But whatever the column I am selecting in "Select" action, automatically it sets to alphabetical order. For example if I select First Name, Last Name, Email ID and Allocation Date, then it take it as Allocation Date, Email ID, First Name and Last Name. And my another doubt is, I am passing the output of "Create HTML Table" to "Send an EMail " action. So how to set the table border.

Comment: @Thanks Frank. You suggestion for table border works for me. But going for Custom option in "Create HTML Table", again leads to space issue in header (I mean instead of "First Name", I am able to deign as "FirstName" only). So please let me any suggestion for header text space issue.

Comment: You can add space in [Logic App Code View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orvDG.png).

Comment: Thanks @Frank Gong. Your solution solve my issue. As you know the flow starts with "Get Entties" action. So is it possible to stop proceeding to next action if there is no results? Because it leads to empty mails. And do you have any suggestions to maintain the template some where else and use it when ever it requires? Because for testing purpose simple template is enough. Later the template become complex, it is difficult to edit in "Send Email" action

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I am solving these two questions for you. I saw you posted a new question. I have already written the answer under the new question, but I don’t know how to maintain the template. You can post another question. , Maybe someone will help you.