# Logic App: Transform json string list to a table in html?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

the logic app currently receives a json string as payload like this through http trigger:

```
{
  "entry": [
    {
      "country": "USA",
      "person": "male",
      "visiting_time": "2023-08-14 12:00:00",
      "Name": "Kyle",
      "Surname": "Doe"
    },
       {
      "country": "Netherlands",
      "person": "female",
      "visiting_time": "2023-08-15 00:00:00",
      "Name": "Juliet",
      "Surname": "McMan"
    },
  ...
      ]
    }
```

How can I transform this json into a html table, so I can send it via Email?

It should look like this in the mail:

| Country | Person | visiting_time | Name | Surname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | male | 2023-08-14 12:00:00 | Kyle | Doe |
| Netherlands | female | 2023-08-15 00:00:00 | Juliet | McMan |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize the result in "Create HTML Table" in Logic Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64698085/how-to-customize-the-result-in-create-html-table-in-logic-apps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and expected results are below:

**`Design:`**

[image]

**`Then:`**

[image]

**`Then:`**

[image]

**`Then:`**

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

**`Codeview:`**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['entry']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Create_HTML_table": {
                "inputs": {
                    "format": "HTML",
                    "from": "@outputs('Compose')"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Table"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "var",
                            "type": "object",
                            "value": {
                                "entry": [
                                    {
                                        "Name": "Kyle",
                                        "Surname": "Doe",
                                        "country": "USA",
                                        "person": "male",
                                        "visiting_time": "2023-08-14 12:00:00"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "Name": "Juliet",
                                        "Surname": "McMan",
                                        "country": "Netherlands",
                                        "person": "female",
                                        "visiting_time": "2023-08-15 00:00:00"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "var2",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "<style>\n#testID1 table, table th, table td {border: 1px solid #0000FF}\n</style>\n<div id=\"testID1\">\n@{body('Create_HTML_table')}\n</div>"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Create_HTML_table": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@variables('var')",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "entry": {
                                "items": {
                                    "properties": {
                                        "Name": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "Surname": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "country": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "person": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "visiting_time": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "required": [
                                        "country",
                                        "person",
                                        "visiting_time",
                                        "Name",
                                        "Surname"
                                    ],
                                    "type": "object"
                                },
                                "type": "array"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            },
            "Send_an_email_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "Body": "<p>@{variables('var2')}<br>\n<br>\n</p>",
                        "Importance": "Normal",
                        "Subject": "IMPORTANT LOGIC APP",
                        "To": "v-rbojja@microsoft.com"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/Mail"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "office365": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3/resourceGroups/v-rbojja/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                    "connectionName": "office365",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/office365"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**`Another way`** is sending directly the output of Create html table to mail like below:

**`Design:`**

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]